# Laravel 4 belongsToMany Relationship Returns Empty

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I'm using Laravel 4, and I'm struggling to set up a many to many relationships. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. Here, I'm trying to establish a many to many relationship between a User and an Organization.

Here's my migration file, creating a users table, an organizations table, and a pivot table to go between the two.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('organizations', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('organization_user', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('organization_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I've also used the default User model, and added the belongsToMany relationship.

```
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
    use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

        use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

        /**
         * The database table used by the model.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $table = 'users';

        /**
         * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

        public function organizations()
        {           
            return $this->belongsToMany('Organization');
        }

    }
```

And I've created an Organization model with the relationship going in the opposite direction.

```
class Organization extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

The issue is if I try to do a query using User::find(1)->organizations(), of course after adding in sample data, it's always returning as an empty array, and the same goes for the opposite direction using Organization::find(1)->users(). The weird part is that if I try to do something like Organization::find(1)->users()->attach(1), it adds the appropriate row within the pivot table, so it knows the relationship is there.

Any ideas on why it seems the queries aren't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the way you're accessing your relations. Try doing the following instead:

```
$organisations = User::find(1)->organisations;

$users = Organisation::find(1)->users;
```

If you use the method version of a relation, you can tack extra things onto the query as well. But be careful, you need to suffix it with `get()` to actually perform the query.

```
// The same as just accessing the property
$organisations = User::find(1)->organisations()->get();

// With extra clauses
$organisations = User::find(1)->organisations()->where('created_at', '>=', '2010-01-01 00:00:00')->get();
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you! I knew it'd be something simple.